# Installing nginx directory stuck with valet install

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I've been trying to intall Laravel Valet but when I run `valet install` either with or without sudo permissions, it gets stuck on the following:

```
Stopping nginx...
Installing nginx configuration...
Installing nginx directory...
```

There aren't any errors in the log and I'm on macOS 12.3.1.

Comment: Go to your home directory and look for `.config `folder check permissions and look inside for valet folder.

Comment: Same problem here, any idea?